# Skype Call Listener For Android

Tags: android, voip, skype

I'm implementing a streaming radio application on android .  The stream must stop when a call comes to the phone or a call is in progress .I have implemented for normal calls (phone calls) but cannot find a proper solution for VOIP calls.If possible I want it to implement it to Viber calls also . Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should listen and monitor ports that use these protocols..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP#Protocols